# Is there any easy way to list stores in android studio? My code seems too lengthy

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I am new to android. I use tutorials to develop programs. i want to list stores with their website and locations. But thing I did is too lengthy. can any one help me out please? I was thinking that forloop would probably help me... But I don't know how to use it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fstore1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/fstoreicon1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_laptop_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/ffacebook1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Store_Name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fstorename1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="20% Off On Bill Over 500 INR"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fmap1" />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fstore2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fstore1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/fstoreicon2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_laptop_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/ffacebook2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Store_Name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fstorename2" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="20% Off On Bill Over 500 INR"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fmap2" />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fstore3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fstore2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/fstoreicon3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_laptop_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/ffacebook3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Store_Name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fstorename3" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="20% Off On Bill Over 500 INR"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fmap3" />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fstore4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fstore3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/fstoreicon4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_laptop_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/ffacebook4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Store_Name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fstorename4" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="20% Off On Bill Over 500 INR"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fmap4" />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/fstore5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fstore4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/fstoreicon5" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_laptop_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/ffacebook5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Store_Name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fstorename5" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="20% Off On Bill Over 500 INR"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fmap5" />


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use listview, than extend it to baseadapter and use baseadapter methods to do this.

Comment: use recylerview http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android list view then create a separate view for list item. Then use base adapter which will use list item to create multiple list items for list view.
Example is here:
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/baseadapter-tutorial-example.html